# Login not working after updating email address

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When the user has registered using the email address as a sign in, all is great, he can logoff and log back in. The problem is when he updates his email address in his profile, he is not able to log in any longer, with the new email nor with the old email since the database reflects the new one.

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();     
    if($_GET["logout"]==1 AND $_SESSION['id']) { session_destroy();
            header("Location:logout.php");      
    }

    include 'connection.php';    
    if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up") {  
        if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
            else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";           
        if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br />Please enter your password";
            else {          
                if (strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="<br />Please enter a password with at least 8 characters";
                if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $_POST['password'])) $error.="<br />Please enter at least 1 capital letter";         
            }

         if ($error) $error = "There were error(s) in your signup details:".$error;
         else {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($results) $error = "That email address is already registered";
            if ($results) $error = "That email address is already registered";
            else {
                $query="INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
                mysqli_query($link, $query);
                $message = "You've been signed up!";
                $_SESSION['id']=mysqli_insert_id($link); 
                header("Location:registration.php");
            }
        }
    }

    if ($_POST['submit']=="Log In") {
        $query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']).$_POST['loginpassword'])."' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($row) {
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];            
                header("Location:dashboard.php");
            } else {
                $loginerror = "We could not find a user with that email and password. Please try again.";            
            }
        }   
?>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);      
    include("connection.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."' LIMIT 1";    
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);                 
        $firstname = $row['firstname'];  $lastname = $row['lastname'];  $gender = $row['gender']; $contact = $row['contact'];  $email = $row['email'];  $password = $row['password'];
        $addressone = $row['addressone'];  $addresstwo = $row['addresstwo'];  $city = $row['city'];  $state = $row['state'];  $zip = $row['zip'];    
?>

<!-- Head -->
<?php include 'includes/head.php'; ?> 

    <form class="form-horizontal" id="registrationForm" method="post" action="insertregistration.php">

        <div class="center">
            <h4 class="text-center">My Profile</h4>
        </div>

    <br /><br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" name="firstname" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" name="lastname" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control" >
                        <option readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>"><?php echo $gender; ?></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="contact">Phone Number</label>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" name="contact" value="<?php echo $contact; ?>">
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-md" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" for="password">Password </label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-md" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                </div>
                    <button input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-kani btn-lg" value="Update Profile"/>
        </div> 

    </form>
```

Comment: This `if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up")` is failing, as is `if ($_POST['submit']=="Log In")` for starters. This `AND $_SESSION['id'])` is not doing anything really. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` inside **all** your files. There are countless other problems with your code.

Comment: Open your MyPHPAdmin and go to: Status > Binary Log. Check out the relevant logs there and see if something was recorded. Also go with what @Fred-ii- has suggested. It's always a good idea to add error reporting while debugging and always make sure that you're covering your bases; handle exceptions before hand so you don't get them. :)